# What's the difference between repo id and repo name on RPM based distributions?

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, command, repository

When I run `yum repolist all` on a Red Hat system, it lists both a "repo ID" and "repo name". I'm confused as to how a single repository has multiple IDs. Is it because a repository can contain others?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`repo id` is the unique identification for the repo whereas `repo name` is just a more meaninful (perhaps) natural language description.

Comment: So apart from being a description, repo name doesn't really serve any purpose? Can the repo name be queried directly via a command? Am I right in thinking that each individual repo id is it's own separate repo and has no affiliation to other repositories despite having similar repo ids to other repos listed under the repo id column? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: "repo name doesn't really serve any purpose" - exactly.